# How to link shared cxx_library to cxx_binary with mingw compiler in Buck?

Tags: mingw, buck

I'm trying to cross compile Windows shared library and binary linked to this shared library with Buck. I set toolchain paths in `.buckconfig`:

```
[mingw]
  prefix = /usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32

[cxx]
  cc = $(config mingw.prefix)-gcc
  cpp = $(config mingw.prefix)-cpp
  ld = $(config mingw.prefix)-ld
  ar = $(config mingw.prefix)-ar
```

Here is `BUCK` file:

```
cxx_library(
    name = 'bar',
    srcs = ['bar.c'],
    headers = ['bar.h'],
    exported_headers = ['bar.h']
)

cxx_binary(
    name = 'foo',
    srcs = ['foo.c'],
    link_style = 'SHARED'
)
```

`foo.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bar_init();
    return 0;
}
```

`bar.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "bar.h"

void bar_init() {
    printf("bar_init successful\n");
}
```

`bar.h`:

```
void bar_init();
```

When I do `buck build //:foo`, I get `/usr/local/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-ld: unrecognised emulation mode: ap` error (due to `-map` option passed to linker, Mac Os linker has it, but GNU linker hasn't, it has `-Map`).

When I add

```
archiver_platform = WINDOWS
linker_platform = WINDOWS
```

to `.buckconfig`, I get `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` `at com.facebook.buck.cxx.WindowsLinker.origin(WindowsLinker.java:88)`. Either it's not supported, or `WINDOWS` means msvc tooling.

Is it possible to build Windows binaries and `.dll`s with Buck? How to do it? (I don't want to run Buck on Windows, cross-compilation with mingw or mingw-w64 is ok).

Update: I was able to make it work by:

1. Setting `linker_platform = GNU` in `.buckconfig` (there are no such option mentioned in [docs](https://buckbuild.com/concept/buckconfig.html#cxx.linker_platform), only in [issue](https://github.com/facebook/buck/issues/1057#issuecomment-267770927))
2. Setting `ld` to `…-gcc` instead of `…-ld` in `.buckconfig`. When invoking `ld` directly, it doesn't support some parameters which are available when invoking via `gcc` frontend.

However, it is not right solution: it creates PE file without extension dynamically linked to file with `.dylib` extension. This executable is runnable with Wine and it loads dynamic lib, but these settings are still not correct.

Comment: Can you post to github project about this problem?

Comment: @tcb uploaded: https://github.com/kolen/buck_mingw_test

Comment: Update: it passes `-map` option to `ld`, Mac OS's `ld` has this option but GNU `ld` hasn't.

Comment: Right now Buck only supports Visual Studio, not MinGW